# Nimbus changing color of the title of a tab

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I would like to change the color from my tabs title.
I tried to set different properties, but nothing is changing.
In my main I set the property `text` to white so all text is white.

Now I would like to change some of the components text, like the tab pane but it is not changing.

```
UIDefaults tabPaneDefaults = new UIDefaults();
tabPaneDefaults.put("textBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.black));
tabPaneSettings.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", tabPaneDefaults);
tabPaneSettings.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults",false);`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think actual value for setting text background is "TabbedPane.background". So your code should start with:

```
UIDefaults tabPaneDefaults = new UIDefaults();
    tabPaneDefaults.put("TabbedPane.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.black));
```

Comment: I tried with this properties and several other but nothing is changing.

Comment: There's something shitty about Nimbus is that I think it doesn't take the `UIDefaults` override for colors.
I have tried many combination to change colors but none of them worked :(

Answer (score 0):

The Nimbus TabbedPaneTabPainter is very complicated. See Oracle:
[TabedPaneTabPainter](https://github.com/conggao/jdkSourceStudy/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/TabbedPaneTabPainter.java)

You have to set

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", *here dark Color*);
```

"nimubsBase" to a dark color.

It looks nice to set buttons, etc. to a matching color. Choose

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", *here light Color*);
```

It takes some time to find a nice pair of colors. Sometimes even little changes have a great effect, sometimes large changes have almost no effect. It is because of the complicated calculation of colors.